# Place an image in front of CSS shapes

Tags: html, css, image, css-shapes

I'm having trouble getting an image to sit IN FRONT of two shapes generated in CSS and HTML. 
I have a rectangle and a top left triangle, but I need an image to sit in front of where these two join. 
JSFIDDLE:  https://jsfiddle.net/fcj9k1w9/

```
<title>LOCALHOST</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="css-preset" href="css/presets/preset1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

<body>

<!--.preloader-->
<div class="preloader"> <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>
<!--/.preloader-->

<header id="home">
<div id="home-slider">
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" style="position:relative; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<div id="rectangle-one"></div>
<div id="triangle-one"></div>
```

Where the placehold.it image is, should be an image logo but I can't get it in front of the two shapes.

Ideally I'd like it to be over the 'seam' as it were - but if it could sit in the centre of the rectangle, that would be great too.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: `position:absolute;` on the image... But you will need to be more clever with your margins, or absolute the CSS generated and manage your `z-index` There are are few ways !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use position: absolute for that.

For example:

HTML:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" class="overlayLogo">
```

CSS:

```
.overlayLogo {
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 99999;
   top: 0;
   left:0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you - exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: How would I se this to the centre of the page, please? 
The way I'm doing it doesn't work 100% for responsive

Comment: I would try placing it in a container that has width: 100%; and then centering it?

Comment: For example:

HTML:
<div class="overlayLogo">
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200">
</div>

.overlayLogo {
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 99999;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   text-align: center;
   top: 0;
   left:0;
}

Answer (score 0):

try :before and :after with the div on which you want to show these shape.

```
#somediv::before{
position:absolute;
content : 'x';
top:0;
left:0;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:gray;


}
```